# In R, how to remove items in vector

Tags: r

In `old_vector`, how to remove items which include `A` or `a`? The result just as `new_vector`. Thanks!

```
old_vector <- c('A','W','AA','C','1a2','123')
new_vector <- c('W','C','123')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R you can [index] with `grepl`:

```
new_vector <- old_vector[!grepl("a", old_vector, ignore.case = TRUE)]
# or
new_vector <- old_vector[!grepl("a|A", old_vector)]

#[1] "W"   "C"   "123"
```

`grep` also has an `invert = TRUE` command that will work:

```
new_vector <- old_vector[grep("a|A", old_vector, invert = TRUE)]
#[1] "W"   "C"   "123"
```

You could also use `grep` *without* indexing using `value = TRUE` (thanks to @Cole for pointing this out!):

```
grep("a", old_vector, ignore.case = TRUE, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# [1] "W"   "C"   "123"
```

Or using `stringr::str_detect` with `negate = TRUE`:

```
new_vector <- old_vector[stringr::str_detect(old_vector, "a|A", negate = TRUE)]
#[1] "W"   "C"   "123"
```

Comment: Probably `grep(..., value = TRUE)` would be the best option. Like `grep("a", old_vector, ignore.case = TRUE, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)`.

Comment: @Cole great! I didnt know the `value = TRUE` function existed - thank you! I have edited my answer to include this option

Answer (score 1):

```
new_vector <- old_vector[grep("a", old_vector, ignore.case = TRUE, invert = TRUE)]
```